# Why are nitriles less basic than amides?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, amides, nitriles

Like nitriles have a localised lone pair which amides do not have, as their lone pair is delocalised and  still amides are more basic. Why?
I could not find any satisfactory explanation so please explain in detail.

Comment: In amides, it's oxygen that is more basic.

Comment: Does not make sense, as nitrogen of cyanide being less electronegative and having a delocalised lone pair must be more basic.

Comment: Well, in protonated amide you get 2 full octet structures, in nitrilium, only one. Such analysis is hardly important, though, it's experimental data that matter. You didn't bring any reference...

Comment: related https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S004040201100545X https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jo800674h

Comment: From tags I assume you mean nitriles like acetonitrile CH3CN and amides of carboxylic acids like acetamide CH3CONH2 (and not anorganic counterparts like KCN and KNH2)

Comment: Yes I meant that